# viewDidAppear no me actualiza las vistas a las medidas reales segun el dispositivo

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

La primera vez que instancio un viewController las medidas de sus vistas del storyboard me las actualiza a las reales del dispositivo.

Asi si hago un self.view.frame.width dentro de viewDidAppear me da el valor de esa medida adaptada según el dispositivo.

Pero si elimino la vista y la vuelvo a instanciar para llamarla de nuevo entonces self.view.frame.width me da siempre el mismo valor fijo de la vista según el storyboard que tengo.

¿ Como hago para que se comporte como la primera vez y me de las medidas adaptadas según el dispositivo ?

Comment: La vista por defecto tiene sus propios constraints, al borrar la vista estas eliminando esos constraints. Al volver a inicializar la vista debes de recrear esos constraints. Aun asi te no te recomiendo borrar la vista del View Controller, es mas común agregar una vista propia sobre la del view controller en viedDidLoad, borrarla cuando hace falta y volverla a agregar usando el frame: self.view.frame

Comment: En realidad no borro los constraints porque cuando la vuelvo a instanciar lo hago del mismo storyboard. ¿  O en este caso tambien se borra las constraints por defecto ?. Quizas no me he explicado bien, lo que borro es el viewController que una vez he instanciado con el storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando storyboards, en los métodos viewWillAppear y viewDidAppear, cuando llamas self.view.frame es posible que el tamaño sea 0 o también puede ser el tamaño del View Controller del storyboard, lo recomendable es usar el método viewDidLayoutSubviews, este se llama después de aplicarse ciertas restricciones de autolayout y es seguro que en este método el tamaño de tu frame sea el del dispositivo.

Comment: Hola amedinam! Gracias por tu aporte, recuerda realizar tus respuestas basandote en [answer]

Comment: Gracias el problema era este y lo he solucionado !

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza viewDidLoad() ya que este es llamado únicamente cuando se crea la view, es decir, la primera vez. De todas maneras, si lo que quieres son las medidas del dispositivo tienes que preguntar por ellas y no por las de la view:

```
UIScreen.main.bounds.width
UIScreen.main.bounds.height
```

Si no pones ni width ni height te devuelve los dos.